# Separate recipes into compatible categories

Tags: algorithms, graphs, colorings

We are running a restaurant. Unfortunately due to mysterious reasons, we cannot tell our chef what **recipes** to make, we can only prepare him the **ingredients** for the meals. Fortunately our chef has memorized all possible **recipes**, therefore if we carefully designate separate **tables** on which we put **recipe** **ingredients** (e.g. ingredients for meal_1 will always go on table_2) he can always make correct meals (he assumes all ingredients for a meal are on one **table**). Of course **tables** are expensive so we want to use as few as possible (the solution does not have to be optimal, but hopefully close to it).

Examples (letters are ingredients and numbers):

These three recipes are ***compatible*** (it is guaranteed that the chef can only make the meals we want him to make) and the ingredients can be on the same table.

- a b -> meal_1
- c d -> meal_2
- a c e -> meal_3

These two recipes are ***incompatible*** and cannot be on the same table, because our chef could just cook meal_5 and have c **ingredient** left.

- a b c -> meal_4
- a b -> meal_5

Here first two recipes are ***compatible***, but the third one is ***incompatible*** and cannot be on this table (n smaller recipes can make a bigger one)

- a b -> meal_6
- c d -> meal_7
- a b c d -> meal_8

Algorithm inputs: recipes (list of ingredients)
Expected output: recipes sorted into sets of compatible recipes (as few sets as possible)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how would an algorithm to solve this problem look like. Sorry if that wasn't clear enough. I think once we have the incompatible recipes figured out, we can use graph coloring algorithms to figure out the number of tables.